# Synchronized two threads not working synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

consider the following code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyObject obj = new MyObject();
        Thread1 t1 = new Thread1(100,'#',obj);
        Thread1 t2 = new Thread1(100,'*',obj);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Thread1 extends Thread {

    int myNum;
    char myChar;
    MyObject myObj;

    public Thread1(int num, char c, MyObject obj){
        myNum = num;
        myChar = c;
        myObj = obj;
    }

    public synchronized void run(){
        for(int i = 1; i<myNum; i++){
            if((i%10)==0)
                System.out.println("");
            System.out.print(myChar);
        }
    }

}
```

*The class MyObject is empty class without anything spacial.
My question is, why the synchronized is not working **and I get printed the '#' and '***' simultaneously and in random order and not one after the other?

Comment: "is not working" is not a problem description. Describe what it ought to do.

Comment: Those are two different threads executing their `run()` method independently. `sychronized()` doesn't come into picture.

Comment: Rohit Jain why the synchronized doesn't come into the picture? I set this run method to be synchronized

Answer (score 5):

Synchronization locks the monitor of an object.  In your case, you are synchronizing against each of the threads objects, that is Thread A locks against Threads A's monitor and Thread B locks against Thread B's monitor.  Thus they are not interacting.

I think that you meant the following for the run() method:

```
public void run(){
  synchronized (myObj) {
    for(int i = 1; i<myNum; i++){
        if((i%10)==0)
            System.out.println("");
        System.out.print(myChar);
    }
  }
}
```

If that was indeed your intended use for myObj, then I would suggest the following change too; as it will help make the code more readable.

Change:

```
MyObject myObj;
```

to:

```
private final MyObject lock;
```

EDIT an alternative approach,  that does not lock against myObj but instead the Thread1's instance of Class.

```
public void run(){
    doJob();
}

private static synchronized void doJob() {
    for(int i = 1; i<myNum; i++){
        if((i%10)==0)
            System.out.println("");
        System.out.print(myChar);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see your point, But if I want to get the same result only by setting the whole method to synchronized and not to use synchronized(myObj) how can I do that? Thanks

Comment: That would imply that both threads shared the same instance of the Thread object.  That cannot be the case.  There are other games that you could play to get a method on a shared instance, such as adding a synchronised method to MyObject or using a static method.  Static methods that are synchronized lock against the Class object, which would be shared between the two threads.  However the run() method cannot be declared static, so again you would have to jump through a couple of hoops to make something like that work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put **thread.join()**, wait for first thread in execution finished to start next one

```
public class hilos {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

        MyObject obj = new MyObject();
        Thread1 t1 = new Thread1(50,'#',obj);
        Thread1 t2 = new Thread1(50,'*',obj);

        Thread[] threads = {t1, t2}; 


        start(threads);


    }


    public synchronized static void start(Thread[] threads) throws InterruptedException{

        synchronized(threads){
            for(int i=0; i < threads.length; i++)   {
                threads[i].start();
                threads[i].join();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
#########
##########
##########
##########
##########*********
**********
**********
**********
**********
```